# Unable to Login to OAM Console for Oracle Access Manager

Tags: oracle, firefox, cookies

I am unable to go to the OAMConsole home page after logging in.

OAM is installed on Centos 6.4 Server Edition and I am accessing the Console via FireFox. I can access Console and Enterprise Manager without any issues. However, when try an access OAM, I get the following error page from FireFox - "The page isn't redirected properly. FireFox has detected that the server is redirecting the request for this address in a way that will never complete. This problem can sometimes be caused by disabling or refusing to accept cookies".

FireFox has been setup to accept cookies, there is NO Webgate and there is NO Load Balancer in the way. All I am trying to do is access the console on the server in which it is installed on.

Logging on to WebLogic Console, I changed the flag on IAMSuiteAgent for OAM from Required to Optional. Rebooted both servers (OAM and Weblogic) and tried again. Now, I am seeing two very different errors:

1. If I type localhost.localdomain:7001/oamconsole - then I see the
   error message I mentioned above
2. If I type localhost:7001/oamconsole - then what I am seeing is
   attempt to login,because the URL changes to the oam console home
   page, but rather actually getting the page, what I get instead is a
   blank page where the last part of the URL is AuthZError.jspx. In the
   Terminal window of WebLogic there is a lot of Java Exceptions which
   seem to me that the authentication itself has failed.

Then I deleted the IAMSuiteAgent in WebLogic, and rebooted the servers again. The error I am seeing now for both versions of the URL is the same error described in 2 above.

So, I am completely stumped!

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have resolved problem by using Centos 6.5 and completely reinstalling software. Also be careful when setting the policy security store to run the patch assistant. There is a bug that the patch fixes without doing this the console will not open.